# In Google Spreadsheet API, how to pass equal sign as value?

Tags: java, spreadsheet, gdata-api

My goal is to inject the cell with =HYPERLINK("text", "link")

So I did this with:

> row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("item",
>   "=hyperlink(\""+a.getAttribute("href")+"\",\""+tds.get(1).getText().replace("=","")+"\")");

But I got error, it won't let me to use =, equal sign, next to hyperlink and I have no idea how to workaround this. Please help. Thanks.